# Regex Help for Account Details

Tags: regex, notepad++, text-files

I've got a text file in the following format

```
======= Account Info =======
email.example@gmail.com:examplepass
Subscription:sub Type
Expiration date:12/21/18
Country:US
Renew Charge:$14.99 + tax
DOB:8/18/73
Created By Athena
============================

======= Account Info =======
email.emaple2@yahoo.com:passExample00
Subscription:sub Type
Expiration date:12/5/18
Country:US
Renew Charge:$14.99 + tax
DOB:8/5/74
Created By Athena
============================
```

How can I use regex to just get email:pass in this format

```
email.example@gmail.com:examplepass
email.emaple2@yahoo.com:passExample00
```

Comment: You need to make your requirements more precise - does the line always start with "email" ? Or are both email and password completely dynamic? Also what characters are allowed/disallowed for both?

Comment: Completely dynamic. All characters are permissible for both

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add this (pretty important) detail.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have any attempt for this?

You can try:

`^email:\w+$`

more comprehensive regex according to your edit would be

`(^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}):\w+`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Updated the post. I don't think I asked the question correctly, but its been fixed

Answer (score 0):

Going by your comment, you need a fairly unrestrictive pattern. Try these:

1) Select everything between the "Account Info" line and the "Subscription" line. You need to check the ". matches newline" checkbox for this to work.

```
(?<=Account Info =======\r\n)(.+?)(?=\r\nSubscription)
```

This does a positive lookbehind for the "Account Info =======" and positive lookahead for "Subscription" and blindly selects everything (except newlines) inbetween.

[Note: Notepad++ doesn't allow variable length lookbehind apparently, so you need to specify the full string for account info. If you're on Unix-based systems, you might need to get rid of the "\r"s]

Cons: Might fail if you have anything else other than email and password between the two lines it looks for.

2) Select everything in a line with `@` and `:`

```
^.+?@.+?:.+
```

Cons: Might fail if you have another line which happens to have both `@` and `:`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\S+@\S+`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\S+     # 1 or more any character that is not a space
@       # literally @
\S+     # 1 or more any character that is not a space
```

[image]